# how to pass values between functions in the same scope

Tags: angularjs

I have 2 functions in the same controller and I am trying to pass the a value from one function to another. But I am getting an error TypeError: Cannot read property 'activeDataset' of undefined

Here is my code:

```
angular.module('daModule').controller("Controller1",Controller1);
    Controller1.$inject = ['$scope', '$timeout'];
function Controller1($scope, $timeout) {
var ct = this;
ct.datasetName = "demo";
...
ct.activeDataset = function activeDataset(){
            return ct.datasetName;

        };
}
```

Here is my other function in the same file

```
function fn1(Controller1) {
...
var currentDataSet = Controller1.activeDataset();
...
}
```

Don't know where I am going wrong.

Comment: Did you try to write your first function as ct.activeDataset = function(){             return ct.datasetName; }; and then after that call it?

Comment: And btw, you should pass ct into fn1 and then call activeDataset() on this ct.

Comment: how can I pass ct to f1? ct is my scope variable for the second function

Comment: I've added example how it can be done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of things going wrong here.

One is that the functions `Controller1` and `fn1` are being defined on the global name space. If another module were to use the same function names, there would be problems. We call this global name space pollution and it should be avoided.

The second problem is that in `Controller1` the value of `this` is not defined until after the function is called. And when it is called, it is set to the local context of when it was called. Attaching properties to `this` in a function call does not make them available as a global property of the function. That is why you are getting "activeDataset undefined" in `fn1`.

To answer your question of how to pass values between functions in the same scope: The functions need to be inside the controller and they should put those values on the `$scope`.

```
angular.module("myApp").controller("myController", [$scope, myController($scope){
    $scope.datasetName = "demo";
    $scope.activeDataSet = function(){
                     return $scope.datasetName;
                 };
    $scope.fn1 = function() {
                     return $scope.activeDataSet();
                 };
}]);
```